# Cant open popup programmatically

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have a map on which im loading the markers with geoJSON.

When the map loads i run a function `buildVisibleSys` which is responsible to build a list of currently visible systems on the map.

That function looks like this:

```
buildVisibleSys = function() {
  var bounds, visibleSys;
  visibleSys = [];
  bounds = map.getBounds();
  return systemLocations.eachLayer(function(marker) {
    var link;
    link = onScreenEl.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
    link.href = '#';
    link.id = "marker" + marker._leaflet_id;
    link.innerHTML = marker.options.title;
    link.onclick = function() {
      marker.openPopup();
      map.panTo(marker.getLatLng());
    };
  });
};
map.on('load', buildVisibleSys);
```

In this function, for each layer im getting some data and building a html block with the names of each marker. Each of those names, associated to the `link` var, have a onclick event attached that will center the map on the correspondent marker. This all works except for the `marker.openPopup()` call i also have on that `onclick` event.

Any idea of what am I missing here?

I've also made a demo of the code available here:
http://jsfiddle.net/lmartins/z8wBW/

UPDATE:
Even more confusing to me is that with mouseover the same method works without a problem, that is, in the function above the following code do open the popup:

```
   link.onmouseover = function(ev) {
      marker.openPopup();
      marker._icon.classList.add('is-active');
    };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your link handler to

```
link.onclick = function(e) {
  marker.openPopup();
  map.panTo(marker.getLatLng());
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

The click of the link to open the popup is bubbling down to the map and closing the popup right after it's opened.

Comment: Amazing. I had a problem closing the popup just after clicking on a link. you save my day.